# The Laplace transform - does it have an associated differential operator, if the kernel is to be viewed as a Green's function?

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms, ordinary-differential-equations

I've begun learning about Green's functions, and if I understand correctly, the Green's function for a linear differential operator $L$ with appropriate boundary conditions is the kernel for the integral transform which transforms the system input into the system output, so if $$Ly=f(x),$$ then $$y(x)=\int_a^b G(x,t)f(t)dt$$

I immediately thought of the Laplace transform:

$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt$$

If the exponential were to be treated as a Green's function, what differential operator would it correspond to?

Comment: Do you know about the inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: You have created two tags ([tag:green]) and ([tag:s-function]) in your question. I have changed it to ([tag:greens-function]) - I suppose this is what you wanted to do. (Although I am not sure to which extent such tag will be useful.)

Comment: @Christopher A. Wong  I know about the Laplace-Mellin integral. I'm guessing this operator is the answer. For some reason I thought only differential operators could have a Green's function attached to them. What are the boundary conditions then? And how does one deal with the fact that the Laplace transform 'changes' the variable? I guess you could always integrate w.r.t. the other variable, right?